# bash looses printf formatting in email process

Tags: bash, format

SO I have to look up competion time for a bunch of procesed in the morning.
Mostly I just have to tail -1 the file and then check the time. I automated  it
into a nice little report.

```
PROCESS            DATE
============================================
topher_time                06:55.192Z
big_sync_morning_time      07:15:45
etime_prod                 07:46.952Z
database_time              08:08:49
trigger                    08:38:13,076
trans_database_time        08:55:33
```

The problem is when I try to mail the report to the group - it comes out all
messed up.
I thought maybe that it was because everyone uses html as a editor/reader in
email so i put some email tags around it - but it is still all messed up.
The report is nicely formatted on the terminal, so I can cut and paste the
report into an email - but when I try to email the report from the program
the formatting is a mess.

```
#!/bin/bash
divider=======================================================
totalwidth=44
header="\n %-18s %-16s \n"
format=" %-18s   %-16s \n"

topher=$(tail -1 /come/and/play/topher.log| ~/walt/convert_gm_est )
big_sync_morning=$(tail -1 /come/and/play/big_sync-morning.log|~/walt/convert_gm_est )
sub_shell=$(tail -1 /come/and/play/trainer.log|~/walt/convert_gm_est )
database=$(tail -1 /come/and/play/with/us/danny/database.log)
trans_c4=$(tail -1 /come/and/play/with/us/danny/regular.sys.log)
trans_database=$(tail -1 /come/and/play/with/us/danny/database.stdout|~/walt/convert_gm_est )


topher_time=$(printf "%s " $topher | awk '{print $1}')
big_sync_morning_time=$(printf "%s " ${big_sync_morning} | awk '{print $1}')
etime_prod=$(printf "%s " ${sub_shell}| awk '{print $1}')
database_time=$(printf "%s " $database | awk '{print $5}')
triggertime=$(printf "%s " $trans_c4 | awk '{print $1}')
trans_database_time=$(printf "%s " $trans_database | awk '{print $5}')

mail -s "morning batch completion times" "capser@casper.com" << END_MAIL
echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<pre>"
printf "$header" PROCESS DATE
printf "%$totalwidth.${totalwidth}s\n" "$divider"
printf "$format" \
topher "$topher_time" \
big_sync_morning "$big_sync_morning_time" \
etime_prod "$etime_prod" \
database "$database_time" \
trans_c4 "$triggertime" \
trans_database "$trans_database_time"

printf "%s\n"
echo "</pre>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"

END_MAIL
```

This is the process when it runs from the command line.

```
PROCESS            DATE
============================================
topher_time                06:55.192Z
big_sync_morning_time      07:15:45
etime_prod                 07:46.952Z
database_time              08:08:49
trigger                    08:38:13,076
trans_database_time        08:55:33
```

This is the mailed report - this is what it looks like in the email .

```
echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<pre>"
printf "\n %-18s %-16s \n" PROCESS DATE
printf "%44.44s\n" "======================================================"
printf " %-18s   %-16s \n" topher_time "06:55.192Z" big_sync_morning_time "" etime_prod "07:46.952Z" database_time "08:08:49" trigger "08:38:13,076" trans_database_time "08:55:33"
printf "%s\n"
echo "</pre>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
```

UPDATE: 
surrounding the commands in a { } and then piping them into a mail command worked - kinda
The grouping the commands does not preserve the printf formatting. 
Is there another way to ensure formatting ?

```
PROCESS            DATE
============================================
topher_time     06:55.192Z
big_sync_morning_time  07:15:45
etime_prod        07:46.952Z
database_time     08:08:49
trigger           08:38:13,076
trans_database_time   08:55:33
```

Comment: A HERE document doesn't execute the lines as commands. They are literal strings except where the shell does variable/etc. expansion. You need to actually execute the commands in the HERE doc to get them to run. Which is why your output is the "script" itself.

Answer (score 3):

You'll notice that it just expanded and printed your commands rather than executing them. To instead pipe in the result of a sequence of commands, use a command group:

```
{
  echo "<html>"
  echo "<body>"
  echo "<pre>"
  printf "$header" PROCESS DATE
  ...
} | mail -s "morning batch completion times" "capser@casper.com"
```

Comment: Or execute all the commands in the here document manually `$(...)` but this is likely better and easier.

Comment: Or even `exec > >(mail -s "morning batch completion times" "capser@casper.com")` before the commands to produce the mail. (And didn't you mean casper@casper.com or capser@capser.com ? :) )